# Why am I getting recent up-votes on a old answer for a question that is now closed?

Tags: support, review, closed-questions, up-votes

I'm getting up-votes on an old question on SO, that was originally down-voted.  This question is now closed.

Apparently, the folks there were against not the answer itself but a rather useless link that it included.

Recently I removed that "offending" link.  Has this edit put me somehow on top of some review queue?

I saw [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20258/any-idea-why-an-answer-will-suddenly-get-a-bunch-of-upvotes-all-at-once) but it does not seem to cover my exact situation.

Comment: Editing does make the question more visible. So yes, if that was the heart of the question.

Comment: @Geobits - Just to be clear.  Will editing of one of many **answers** make the **question** more visible.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes; editing (or posting) answers can bump the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People viewing the [active questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) see questions where changes happened (editing, new posts, comments, etc.), even if the question is old.

Comment: The question already has an accepted answer (obviously not mine) and the question is **closed**. Will it still be considered **active** just because one of the answers was updated?

Comment: Yes, activity on the question is all that matters.

Answer (score 2):

When looking at questions you can sort them by newest, which is based on when they were first posted, or by activity, which is base don the last time the question or any answer was posted or edited.  (Or one of a number of other sorting options, such as votes.)  By editing a post you move it to the top of that "active" view.

It's also possible that someone else came across the question through Google (or searching directly on SO).  Perhaps it was someone else who has the same issue/question and is upvoting it to indicate their support of it.