# Show in linked/related questions sidebar whether a question has answers or not

Tags: feature-request, design, related-questions, linked-questions, sidebar

Currently, in the linked/related sidebar, without opening the question the user can only distinguish whether the question has an *accepted* answer (green icon) or not (grey icon).

I often eagerly open an interesting-sounding question with a grey icon, only to find myself disappointed because it has no answer yet.

To avoid this, I suggest adding a **third type of icon** for questions that have at least one answer, but no accepted one. Probably a darker/lighter icon or some kind of frame or glow. I've made a quick example with Paint (if relevant, the screenshot I used is from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66651/)). I'm in no way satisfied with the look of it, but at least it demonstrates the general idea.

[image: Example]

What do you think about this proposal? Would it be a useful addition to the StackExchange interface?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172630/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems interesting. In the mean time [I've made a userscript to do it](https://stackapps.com/questions/7398/sidebar-answer-status).

This will draw a border around answered questions, and will also set the tooltip to the answer count. It uses the text color for the border color so as to match the site's theme. Note that this uses `is_answered` from the API, which doesn't behave exactly like the OP's request: A question is "answered" if it has an accepted answer or an answer *with a positive score*, although you may change the condition where indicated on line 81 if you'd prefer to define it as > 0 answers.

> [image]

This will cache sidebar results for 30 minutes in an attempt to reduce API queries, especially when revisiting the same post later. It makes at most one API query per page load, you get something like 300 per day I think.