# Auto protect questions with a sudden influx of viewers

Tags: feature-request, traffic, protected-questions, noise-reduction

A sudden, large increase in viewers, for instance from Reddit, can result in no small amount of noise and spam, as it more often than not occurs when there's a contentious topic at hand.

It may be worthwhile considering detecting sudden surges of traffic targeted at a given question and protecting them for a 48 hour period to prevent spurious posting.

Comment: This is kinda like the next level of the ["reddited indicator" suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76364/show-whether-a-question-was-reddited).

Comment: @Pop Yes, and in fact was triggered by it.

Comment: Uh... Just to clarify: "protecting" a question (in the sense that the term is used by the SO engine - see Grace's link) just prevents answers from low-rep users. It makes sense when a question is getting, say, tons of Google traffic. Is this *really* necessary for a short-term bump in referrals from a single source?

Comment: Before the day ends someone will suggest trying to block all users who ever visited reddit :)

Comment: @Trufa: As a redditor for 5 years, I'd have to oppose that.  ;)

Comment: @Bill What are you some sort of founding member of the sect? :) - This is my last smily face, from now on, asume I always mean it nicely.

Comment: @Trufa: Yes, I joined reddit when the front page was all Paul Graham and Joel Spolsky articles.

Comment: @Bill Damn that a lot of time.