# Can the protect feature be made to block "101" users as well?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, protected-questions

Somewhat in the same spirit as [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76371), and somewhat inspired by my (recent!) discovery that [one now needs 125 reputation to downvote stuff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down), I have to ask:

> Can the [question protection feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/protect-questions) be modified so that users with less than or equal to 101 reputation cannot answer protected questions?

Additionally, I would propose that the threshold for posting in protected questions be raised to the same level as that for downvoting; that is, 125 rep. (If there are other justifiable values, well...)

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71874) from math.SE features a rather irrelevant answer given by a 101-rep user. I understand that this request, if granted, would have prevented the 15-rep user who at least had the courtesy to post something pertinent for the question, but I was thinking in the same line as preventing "drive-by" downvoting by 101-rep users. [This (rather infamous) question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17152) also acquired a few irrelevant answers by 101 rep users (which have subsequently been deleted) until protection. (I believe there are other examples, but I can't seem to find them.)

(Since this is a meta-site, I wouldn't mind downvotes from people who disagree, but I sure would also be interested in seeing reasons why this feature request should **not** be implemented, in the interest of finding out my biases/blind spots.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Downvotes that go "poof". Odd...

Comment: For the record, protection on that question didn't happen until *after* that user's answer had been posted.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that filigree. Thanks @Grace.

Comment: As I said, I was hoping to see reasons for disagreement, but I guess people are just gorram lazy and clicking a button is easier for their wrists... :P

Comment: Would it not have been simpler just to raise the threshold to 111?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Apparently, this is [already being done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question).

> ### Who can answer a protected question?
>
> Users with 10 or more reputation can answer a protected question. However, **the +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check**, so you must have earned 10 or more reputation *on that specific site* to answer a protected question.

Of course, this wouldn't block someone who reached 101 rep without the association bonus, but I think this is in the same spirit as your request.

Comment: I see. Should this question be closed as a dupe?

Comment: More to the point, shouldn't this be added to the list of [feature changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445)?

Comment: @Chris Should it? I mean, Jeff Atwood edited that part in, but I have no idea when that actually changed, or even if it changed at all. Maybe it worked like this since protected questions were introduced, and the FAQ post was just missing that bit of info.

Comment: Hm, good point. Just throwing it out there...

Comment: I don't see the bold part of the message here meta.superuser.com/questions/3877/cant-post-answer-on-community-blocked-question-have-enough-points/3897#3897

Comment: What's the point of the +100 account association bonus then? "We're giving you 100 points because we trust you on other sites"... just not here?