# Include 101 rep users (i.e. those with the association bonus) in first questions/first answers within the review page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, new-users

## Problem

This is behaviour I have been noticing for quite a while on [Biology.SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com).

Consider [this user](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/542/hermann-ingjaldsson) who after 42 days on the site posted two answers for the first time this morning.  Yet neither one of them arrived in the "First Answer" section of the review tools. Neither post had received any upvotes, and I was careful not to load them in normal question view before going to the review pages.

I can only assume that this is:

1. <del>Because the user has been registered for an extended period of time - though I'm sure this shouldn't exclude them from the review queue</del>*
2. *More likely* because the user has not got 1 rep as they have received the association bonus from Stack Overflow.

If it is the second case then I would be inclined to argue that the association bonus should not exempt you from the review queue on another site, for example the on/off topic distinctions for Biology or another science site are likely to be hugely different from those on Stack Overflow - therefore it might be helpful to have more established users check it over.

**Is this normal behaviour?**

<sup>* This has happened twice more today with new users so it's not related to lurkers.</sup>

---

## Feature Request

**Include users with 101 reputation in the first post review screens in addition to those with 1 reputation to account for users new to a specific stack.**

I'm now turning this into a feature request as I've noticed quite often that I'm editing posts by 101 rep users when I find them (for example, using [DOI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier) links which are in less common use on non-science stacks) - it would be nice to have these plumped in with the rest of the first questions rather than being surprised by them when I'm in a learning mood rather than an editing one!

Comment: related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109117/can-the-protect-feature-be-made-to-block-101-users-as-well/109118#109118

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the introduction of [the new First Posts Review Queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts/), this is done.

The first post made by *anyone* on the site will be featured in this queue for 30 days after they post it (excluding closed and deleted posts). Association bonuses, time spent on the site (and, for now at least, reputation as a whole) are ignored.

Comment: Is this still happening as above?  [This question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/6871/why-do-humans-alone-have-the-capability-to-have-religious-spiritual-experiences) asked by [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/users/2958/deostroll) "new today" member didn't appear in the First Posts review queue and shows no Review History in mod tools.  I've noticed this on a few other occasions too.

Comment: And even [this post](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/6866/69) by a one rep user joined today didn't show up or show any reviews done in mod tools.

Comment: That last one wasn't actually his first post - there was a question that got in before it. The first one [*did* make it into the queue](http://biology.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/1123) (about two minutes after you posted the comment), but for some reason isn't listed in the mod tools; I'll look into that.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look; the first one has now made it into *my* queue, perhaps I was being over eager with the caching, however I'm still sure it's been longer in the past.

Comment: There are a bunch of restrictions that aren't mentioned here; maybe I'll document them at some point once I'm sure they're stable. For instance, there's a 15-minute wait between a first post and entry into the queue, and you won't see posts in *your* queue that you've already acted on in some way.

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think on balance I agree with what you're asking - it's sometimes slightly frustrating to think "I've got so much rep over on site X, and I'm a mod on site y, why do I have to prove myself further here", but then I stop and think "Yes, perhaps their ideals are different to my other sites" and I'll wait for my edits to be approved ;)

Comment: I kindof sortof agree with this, but remember that mods are users extraordinaire, and while they may not be familiar with the community of sites other than their own, but they (imo) can be trusted not to mess around with others sites until they do. That being said, I see no major benefit to it, so I wouldn't _necessarily_ recommend it.