# New first-post review queue: "Upvoted comment" should be a valid action

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

The first post I saw in the [new first-post review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts) had **three** "Please post the code" comments, all without a single upvote. That's pretty noisy, ugly and not helpful to anyone

So upvoting a comment should be considered a valid action that enables the "I'm done" button.

Comment: It would also be needed for *low quality* “link only” answers. When the answer is not worth deletion, there's nothing much to do except to upvote the previous comment which says links only answers are lame.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Voting up a comment is now considered a valid review action on the [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) and [Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) review queues.