# Project HoneyPot Review Feature Bug

Tags: bug, review

I was recently carrying out a few reviews on SO when I came across one of the [Honeypot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152709/improving-the-quality-of-reviews-project-honeypot) ones.  I believe that there was a bug with it however in that when I went to view the question, it said "question not found" (See image below).

> [image: HoneyPot Review Image]

I think that this is a bug and needs fixed.

Another thing I think is wrong is the description in the "Congratulations" message. I believe that flagging the post as "Not an answer" should be acceptable in this case also.

Edit: As Ral Zarek [pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156988/project-honeypot-review-feature-bug#comment452566_156988), the vote to close post should not appear for an answer as a valid option either.

Comment: No, the answer should **not** be flagged as spam. Reserve that for actual spam (unwanted commercial messages).

Comment: @MartijnPieters was faster, this is not spam. *But* I agree with "not an answer", that seems to be the appropriate flag to me.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit out the spam message. I would still be tempted though if a users answers consisted of these kind of comments alone however.

Comment: What bugs me more about the description is "voting to close", as this is an answer.

Comment: Never noticed that one. Will add it to the question. I don't have the vote to close privilege yet so have never used it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters On second thoughts, using the 'It needs moderator attention' -> 'Other' would be more suitable for flagging it if the users activity only consisted of posting these types of comments. This would come up as one flag with an explanation attached as opposed to many spam flags that will only serve to increase moderator workload.

Comment: @Ren: Only if I saw that user post the same message a few times. Generally, I'd make that one a "Not an answer", leave a comment to that effect, and move on.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, will keep that in mind for the future. Thanks for the assistance :)

Comment: Worth pointing out http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156938/169404