# Poorly formatted honeypot item in low quality posts is claimed "high-quality as-is", editing triggers audit failure

Tags: support, edits, low-quality-posts, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I came across a post that was of OK quality, but poorly formatted. Clicking "Edit" I got back

> This post already looks pretty good! While there are probably minor
>   improvements that can be made, this would be considered a high-quality
>   post as-is. You should click Looks Good when reviewing such posts,
>   editing only when you can make substantial improvements.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately - but
>   please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the
>   guidance shown above.

It was not a high quality post due to its poor formatting. Readability was at a low since the question was all on one line. I was merely trying to edit it before clicking "Looks good".

Can this UX be improved by letting me edit it before the system draws a conclusion on whether or not I took the bait?

*This is the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1136695) in question. It even says that I have edited, but alas I did not get that far because of the audit system.*

---

- For the record, post content [at the time of my review](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13694406/2) looked as follows:

  > I have a data.table which has two keys: Year (10 levels) and MemberID (200,000 levels). When I setkey, does setkey(MemberID, Year) results in different performance compare with setkey(Year, MemberID)? If so, which way will be better?

Comment: related (not a duplicate) report about another kind of premature completion of [tag:review-audits] test: [“STOP! Look and Listen” audit tricked me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156938/165773) _'...I am told if I pass/fail BEFORE clicking "I'm Done" giving me no chance to undo an upvote or to perform 2 actions..'_

Comment: There are two problems that this is pointing out.  The first is that there is an audit item for one that has significant problems demanding review, and also that when the audit thinks an item is good, odds are no matter how good it is there's someone who can legitimately find need to edit it, so editing such an item shouldn't result in "failing" the audit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The audit system is very broken. I pointed this out in my question, ["STOP! Look and Listen" audit tricked me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156938/169404). I was almost nagging a diamond to fix some of the issues but all I really got as a response was:

> The intent is to also not waste a reviewers time with reviewing in detail any post that is an audit. If an audit is being performed make it as swift as possible, give guidance, and move on to something more important

But the audit is giving **false guidance**. There are still ways to get around the current audit system that will allow you to pass 100% of the time. *However, you shouldn't have to cheat to perform the correct action.*

Answer (score 2):

Editing known-good posts should not lead to failure in future Low Quality audits. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168218/an-edit-is-a-looks-good-when-not-being-audited-and-not-one-when-doing-an-audit/168406#168406) for details.