# An edit is a Looks Good when not being audited and not one when doing an audit?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits, low-quality-posts

> Related: [Editing a Low Quality question is an implicit "looks good"; it shouldn't be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160064/editing-a-low-quality-question-is-an-implicit-looks-good-it-shouldnt-be)

I just failed an audit in the Low Quality review queue. [This one to be precise](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1554431).

Here's a screenshot.

> [image: review audit failure]

The question in question has multiple miscapitalised words; "please help" appended and some useless information. Editing is a perfectly valid response in the Low Quality queue.

What's slightly galling is that edit is an implicit looks good; as I prove in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160064/editing-a-low-quality-question-is-an-implicit-looks-good-it-shouldnt-be) and can back up with this [recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1554388).

Why is an edit a Looks Good when not being audited and not one when doing an audit?

Comment: Given the fact that the question is not deleted, closed, and has lots of downvotes, I think the audit actually wanted you to say it looks good, even though this post clearly needs quite a lot of editing.

Comment: I recognise that @Servy; I can prove that "edit" == "looks good". I don't believe it should but I'm using that information to edit the question; it needs it and I don't want to delete it. I'm beginning to think [the edit button should just be removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168219/remove-editing-as-an-button-option-from-the-low-quality-queue).

Comment: related: [Poorly formatted honeypot item in low quality posts is claimed “high-quality as-is”, editing triggers audit failure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157808/165773)

Comment: I think it should be closed as opinion based

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edits should not count as failures when the audit is a known-good post. While editing a train-wreck of a question or non-answer is probably a waste of time, even small improvements to an already-good post can be useful.

And as you say, edits are normally counted as a strong vote of confidence in the post. So counting them as failures when the audit contains something of quality makes no sense.

Marking this as a bug. And, sorry for the confusion!

**EDIT**

This is fixed now – editing an audit post that we know to be good is now considered an audit pass, rather than a failure.

Comment: @Emmett, if editing when it looks good is a pass, and presumably editing when it looks bad is a pass, what's to stop people using edit as a catch-all pass method?

Comment: Editing known-bad posts in the LQ queue will fail the review, @staticbeast. By and large, these posts are beyond help.

Comment: Excellent, just checking it wasn't a two steps forward, one step back situation.