# Remove editing as an button option from the Low Quality queue

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

> Related:
>    - [Editing a Low Quality question is an implicit "looks good"; it shouldn't be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160064/editing-a-low-quality-question-is-an-implicit-looks-good-it-shouldnt-be)
>    - [An edit is a Looks Good when not being audited and not one when doing an audit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168218/editing-fails-a-low-quality-audit)

I now have two questions about the contradictory behaviour of editing in the Low Quality queue.

Can we please just remove editing from the equation completely? Someone should be able to edit a post and then say I'm not sure.

- A single edit should not remove a question from the queue. Though people may argue that other's shouldn't be editing crap this is [provably not the case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160064/editing-a-low-quality-question-is-an-implicit-looks-good-it-shouldnt-be).
- An edit should not be a audit failure. Editing does not mean that I am recommending that the post be deleted.

Allow people to edit a post in the ordinary way (link at the bottom of the post) and then force them to either make a decision keep/remove or to say I don't know; I'm going to skip.