# When asked to take a break from reviewing I still get the "please review it" pop up

Tags: bug, review, edits

I am still blocked from reviewing on SO as mentioned in [Review audits are too error-prone when reviewing on a mobile device](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165682/169404) yet I can still see the message that says, "1 edit to this post is pending, please review it"

[image: please review it popup]

Of course, when I click it I get the message:

> You have failed too many recent review audits – looks like you might need a break. Come back in 15 hours to continue reviewing.

The "please review it" popup shouldn't be displayed for blocked users.

Comment: would "please review it if you can" be acceptable?

Comment: Meh. Who cares about the tiny tooltip? If it shoved an alert in one's face begging to do a review, okay, but this...