# My fingers are too fat for the "No further action" dialog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, design, flag-queue

It's Sunday afternoon. It's snowing outside, and I have a pounding headache. A perfect time to go through the flags queue on my little tablet.

...Except, some of the flags are completely bogus. And the "declined..." link is entirely too close to the "helpful" button for me to hit it accurately.

[image: my fat finger]

There's no way to "undo" a misclick on "helpful", so I've already given three unhelpful flags a stamp of approval when nothing needed to be done. If I zoom way, waaaay in, and tap *very* carefully, I can usually mash the link, but even then sometimes Android seems to think I'm aiming for that button.

[image: still fat]

I can't help but think that just a little bit of whitespace, maybe just an extra line, would suffice to avoid this problem.

---

The small bit of added space did the trick. Action shot:

[image: beats Finger-Slim-Fast]

Comment: And no, skipping crepes for breakfast is not a work-around.

Comment: I think you accidentally a word. :)

Comment: You're a better man than me. I have a pounding headache, too, but reviewing flags is about the last thing that would have come to my mind. I'm watching the third season of *Dexter* instead.

Comment: Ah, good plan! Nothing like watching people cut into pieces and bagged to put a little bit of head pain into perspective. @Pekka웃

Comment: @Shog9 crepes? *crepes?* You **monster.** You horrible, traitorous, [monster](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/waffles).

Comment: The solution is obviously to get new fingers.

Comment: What are these numbers in the upper right corner for? Load time for each flag?

Comment: That's MiniProfiler, @toscho - just timings for various parts of page generation. And yes, it kinda gets in the way when you zoom way in on mobile.

Comment: I have been complaining about this stuff for quite some time. The only relevant feedback I have got is to **not** use a mobile device. (stupid, I know!)

Comment: Very interesting that my question, [Review audits are too error-prone when reviewing on a mobile device](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165682/169404), gets so many downvotes and horrible advice yet this question doesn't.

Comment: @Austin true; to be fair though, you *did* ask for the reviews to be made more forgiving, which is not entirely what is asked here. To his credit, Shog's been pretty consistent.... quoting him on your question: `The solution to that would be a better mobile design for review`

Comment: @Pekka웃 I agree with you. I only asked for it to be more forgiving because the mods/staff rejected my request to fix the interface (allow for actions to be undone) back in November.

Comment: Just to clarify for the close voters: this has absolutely nothing to do with /review.

Comment: Surprised nobody here suggested it yet... what about stylus for your mobile device? It's surely thinner than your fingers. :D

Comment: @AustinHenley I upvoted your question because I've experienced how frustrating it is on a mobile device to hit links etc accurately, even when zoomed in (edit, no, edit, EDIT, no, _EDIT_. I said EDIT arrrggggghhh). You seem to want to know why this gets more votes than yours, sorry in advance if you didn't want me to give reasons: This question made me say "awesome question". It uses self-deprecating humour and pictures to get its point across where you used lots of text and linked it to a complaint - that's why this question is more appealing, which is probably why it gets lots of upvotes.

Comment: note to self: at next [meta-tag:election]s, request for an additional requirement for mods to have fingers (better yet, _claws_) thin enough for stuff like that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Added extra linebreak between the `helpful` button & `decline` link.

Based on guesswork regarding OPs finger size.

Should be out in the next build. Let me know if your fingers are fatter than I extrapolated.

Comment: Can't you write code that will measure the user finger size?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - phase 2. This is a quick fix for now. Next version will handle all manner of users - mice to elephants.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: As far as I know, that is responsibility of the OS. Don't forget that the browser only sees (multiple) cursors, and not the original finger-press anymore.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby - Actually, we will be querying some Google APIs. They know **everything**.

Comment: @Oder indeed, even [if user is actually a goat](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13375357/447356)!

Comment: Thanks, Oded - did the trick.

Answer (score 10):

The solution suggested by the operator in [The Simpsons](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DtbPOXFk00) was to "mash the keypad with your palm" when his fingers were too fat to dial.

[image]

It fits nicely with your activity as well.  When you want to decline a flag, just mash the tablet with your palm.

Comment: It is a horrible solution. Especially if you apply this "solution" to this same problem in the review queues. The audits will hit you hard.

Comment: Relax.  It's a joke.

Comment: Joke? *JOKE?* **I DO THIS NOW**.

Comment: I would love a gesture-based mod UI. Particularly if it had that gesture. And... one other one.

Comment: @Shog9 [We kind of have the other gesture now](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o7xGp.jpg)

Answer (score 8):

What if we just made it a standard button? It could then be the same size as the helpful button.

Comment: It's made a link to make it a secondary action http://uxmovement.com/buttons/the-visual-weight-of-primary-and-secondary-action-buttons/

Comment: @BenBrocka: That makes sense with the old "dismiss as helpful" policy, but now that moderators are being more strict with helpful flags, it seems like it's not-so-secondary anymore.

Comment: "stricter" meaning "no longer marking as helpful flags that are completely wrong", @anim. It's still a secondary action.

Comment: @BenBrocka: For one, we're mods. We know what is helpful and what isn't, so visual cues aren't that useful. Secondly, declining is just as important as helpful-ing. The only difference is that we get lots more good flags than bad.