# Can't view Review History and Stats when temporarily banned from reviewing?

Tags: feature-request, review, review-stats, review-suspension

When banned from reviewing, the "History" and "Stats" tabs are not displayed and the link saying "Recent reviews" is also invisible.

This makes it impossible to navigate to the Stats pages such as https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats without typing in the URL directly. I also have no idea how to view my Review History now.

Can a link be added so that users can still see their history and stats when this is displayed?:

> You have failed too many recent review audits – looks like you might need a break.

Comment: Why? You're banned, the stats aren't going to change until the ban is lifted.

Comment: @Yannis Yes, the stats *do* change for other users. Half of the stats page is Top Reviewers. This changes. Also, I don't have *my* stats memorized.

Comment: Again: Why would you even want to look at the stats while banned?

Comment: I know what top reviewers is, but that's _not_ my question, my question is: Why looking at the review stats while banned is useful to the community to the point that a developer should invest time fixing this. Especially when there's an awesome workaround: **Don't get banned.**

Comment: @Yannis Because it should have never been designed like this in the first place. There is no reason for preventing users from seeing the stats page. Either all users should be able to see it or don't have it at all. Also, your workaround isn't a good one. Typing in the URL is. But I shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: @Yannis Please see my question which explains the **false** reason that I was banned: [Review audits are too error-prone when reviewing on a mobile device](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165682/169404)

Comment: [Seriously - just slow down a bit, take time to read the post you're reviewing.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165682/review-audits-are-too-error-prone-when-reviewing-on-a-mobile-device#comment489632_167039)

Comment: @Yannis I read that and that doesn't answer my question. What does that have to do with viewing the stats page which **should** be visible?

Comment: @AustinHenley Does this also affect viewing the review *history*? Or just the stats page?

Comment: @EliahKagan Both, thanks for pointing that out. I have no idea how to view my history when that link isn't shown which would definitely be helpful. I have edited my question.

Comment: I would love to hear your thoughts on this @Shog9 after our discussion earlier.

Comment: At first I tended to agree with Yannis here as the message says "looks like you might need a break" - so why view stats while on a break? But then you have a valid point that the direct link still works meaning you are not banned from viewing the stats, so hiding the links is not really the proper thing to do. I believe it's simple design overlook, not planned decision.

Comment: Sorry this may be rude, but I advise you to change the focus from quantity to quality. In the end, reviewing is a tool to improve the site, not to generate halls of fame.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe That is somewhat off-topic. The question isn't about being banned, it is about the design oversight that banned users deal with. I am only one user so don't focus on just my banning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Allowing/Encouraging Banned Reviewers to View History/Stats is Helpful to the Community

If I were banned from reviewing, I would want to *immediately* view my history tab to see what I had done wrong and what could be improved. I would want to understand my mistakes *before* it was time for me to go back and review again. (In the event that I thought I was wrongly banned, I would also want to figure that out while I was still banned. And *with this information, I might come to the conclusion that I was not wrongly banned*.)

It would be especially handy for me to see the posts I had reviewed recently, and look at *what other reviewers did with them*.

It's somewhat less important that people be able to view the stats, but *that is still important*. Another thing I might want to do would be to look reviews by others--especially top reviewers. By comparing my practices to theirs, I might come to see what I had been doing differently.

Fundamentally, even if providing access to history and stats were not **basically helpful toward helping people review better**, there would *still* be no good reason to disable the history and stats links. All the reasons people click them are applicable to people who, for any reason, are not reviewing posts right now. I can look at the history and stats pages for review queues where I cannot currently review posts (because I've hit the daily limit, say, or because I've run out of votes of some kind or other).

There are only two sorts of reasons that would make the current stats and history link behavior correct:

- It might be correct if people who are banned from reviewing were able, and likely, to use the information there for destructive purposes. This seems implausible.
- It might be correct if it were intended as a punishment for reviewing poorly. But the purpose of banning people from reviewing is not to punish them. Furthermore, this would be a counterproductive punishment--as explained above, it isolates people from helpful information about how to do better.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see why the stats page is important. It can only be used for the comparison of the top X users, and then only the absolute number of reviews they've done. Watching other people climb away from you might be painful when banned but if that's the reason you're reviewing its not really a surprise.