# Incorrect failed audit count

Tags: support, bug, review-audits

I recently failed an edit (started with a comment, instead of downvoting first). It marked the audit as failed, and blocked me from reviewing for two days, saying that I had failed too many recent audits. the catch: **I had just passed two audits, after not receiving audits while reviewing for weeks.** This leads me to think that the audit counter may be off, or just bans reviews after just 1 failed audit.

I know this calls for support, but I am not sure if it is a bug or not. Is this by design, or am I the victim of a glitch?

Comment: Commenting counts as failing an audit? That doesn't sound...right

Comment: @BenBrocka from test design perspective, review audits are [suboptimal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156942/165773 "details here")... softly speaking

Comment: I placed a comment before downvoting, and it called me on it immediately, not allowing me to try to fix the post

Comment: Wait, it keeps **track** of failed audits‽ I just failed one in SU because it was a trap with no possible way of not failing. If I knew that this was possible and that it records them, then I would not have bothered. In fact, I am no longer doing reviews **at all**. Why should I? In fact, the very idea that it audits even top-tier users is insulting.