# I failed a review audit by clicking Improve

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

See: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1581133.

I clicked <kbd>Improve</kbd> to see what exactly has been changed in the title. And then StackOverflow told me that I failed a review audit.

Now, what should I do?

Comment: And by the way I wanted to uppercase these lowercase i's!

Comment: Look at the mark-down difference to see the difference, you don't need to click on `Edit`. Clicking on `Edit` will be registered in the system as making an action on the post, which I think is a bit stupid here.

Comment: This does not work for titles.

Comment: You really don't have to do anything. Well, besides being more careful next time. It's a terrible (fake) suggested edit, which should really have been rejected.

Comment: The preview clearly shows the new title as: "How to running can i forcing invalidate valid stop a TimerTask Handler?" — what would be there to check, really?

Comment: @nalply: Sorry, I think I mistook that for the markdown diff in regular post.

Comment: Duh, I am stupid, now I understand the title... :-)

Comment: The edit was completely bogus, but I don't understand why trying to Improve a suggested edit counts as an audit failure, given that the question _did_ have things that could have been improved, and the suggestion can be marked "unhelpful" and thus rejected from the Improve interface.

Comment: Related:  The weirdly-titled http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156938/stop-look-and-listen-audit-tricked-me since audits aren't pass/fail on submission but rather first action.

Comment: Just wondering: Is that user who "suggested" the edit real?

Comment: @RobW - Yes, they're randomly selected (I believe from people who've recently submitted suggested edits), same with the edit captions, which are pulled from real ones. The content is total Markov chain garbage, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that clicking "Improve" should not trigger automatic failure of the audit as it's **not** always approve.

Only if you leave the "Suggested edit was helpful" checkbox ticked and click "Save Edits" then you'll fail the audit, otherwise you'll pass.

Comment: It is still possible to bypass the audit when one is not editing the post properly, but still uncheck the checkbox...

Comment: @nhahtdh, perhaps this can be caught by a threshold set for that post. If someone spends little time *and* also edits very little, he fails the audit. But I think we should keep the review audit system as simple as possible and accept some false positives like mine.

Comment: I personally think it would be even worse to finish a full constructive edit, only to find out it was a review audit and your work was wasted.

Comment: @Wildcard good point which I totally missed! Will have to rethink this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I messed up. I am going to suck up the consequences of my mistake.

It happened this way:

1. I opened the fake edit suggestion.
2. I didn't understand the title.
3. I stopped reading at the title.
4. I clicked the mark-down difference.
5. This does not help for titles.
6. Then I decided to "enter" the post and see what I can do and clicked <kbd>Improve</kbd>.
7. BOOOM. It was a review audit.

Comment: Now I passed a different review audit: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1583426 - StackOverflow you rule.