# Why is clicking "flag" in a review immediately counted as failed

Tags: support, flags, review-audits

In my latest review https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3550708 I was immediately locked when I accidentally clicked the flag link.

The question how I was able to click the link accidentally can be easily answered with, I did but I don't know either.

Why is clicking "flag" immediately counted as failed even if the flag workflow can be canceled?

Comment: @mehow, it's also pretty similar to what I described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169580/improve-treated-as-improper-response-to-proper-response-to-audit/210577#210577), although in all fairness - clicking something by accident is not as frustrating - there was no real reason to flag that post

Comment: The audits are designed to catch your first instinct.  Yes, this means that accidental misclicks happen, but unless they happen repeatedly, it won't matter much