# Reject and Improve buttons are too close

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

The buttons are too close (especially on high resolution) and I tend to hit `Improve` instead of `Reject` 1 out of 20 times or so.

Most times I simply cancel and reject the edit, but when it's a "test" I fail it and now I'm banned for 2 days of review.

It would be much easier if the `Improve` button was the rightest one.

Comment: So be more careful...

Comment: @scrblnrd3 I can't be the only one that happens to.

Comment: The real problem then is that you review too fast. Take your time. It's not a contest.

Comment: My comment was mostly tongue in cheek, but I don't see how this would fix anything; people would just click on the wrong thing anyway, it just wouldn't be the `Improve` button

Comment: @scrblnrd3 it would be the `Next` button, that would be harmless.

Comment: @juergend not really. It's a simple misclick with a great penalty.

Comment: If you misclick it frequently enough that you're getting review-banned, then you should probably just slow down...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169580/improve-treated-as-improper-response-to-proper-response-to-audit regarding failing audits from clicking improve

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow It happened no more than 3 times. ever.

Comment: @AlienArrays Only if after a misclick you keep editing the post and submit it. Not really what im talking about.