# Add feedback for review audits

Tags: feature-request, review, review-audits, feedback

Having just tripped a review audit I disagree with, and having already [complained in another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169580/improve-treated-as-improper-response-to-proper-response-to-audit) about these types of things, I realized an important step that could be used to help in the future.

How about we have a "feedback" link specifically for when an audit has been failed so that we can directly give a message on what we disagree with in the audit.  This way The Team could review their reviews based on the feedback and may change some of them, or improve the system in some way.