# Why is improving a suggested edit considered an audit failure?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I was doing some reviewing on Stack Overflow and saw one question that had a serious (wrong) spelling edit.

I wanted to reject it straight away, but I wanted to correct it first, since the original question wasn't OK either, so I clicked "Improve" instead.

However, it turned out this was an audit question; I was [admonished](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/admonish#Verb) that I should have rejected it and not edit!

I understand, but what if (as it was the case) I wanted to improve and uncheck the 'helpful' button instead?

Comment: `improve`, then uncheck the "this suggestion was helpful" box.

Comment: @DanielFischer it didn't have that option, it threw the notice straight away. Is that a bug then?

Comment: @jackJoe: Are you saying you clicked 'Improve' instead of 'Approve'? If so, then I would consider that a bug.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok, but I don't see any other way to edit the question/answer when reviewing (unless the option that Daniel mentioned is shown).

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, I clicked improve.

Comment: @jackJoe it's a bug in the "SO mod tester tool". It should not mark `Improve` as a wrong answer on a test edit IMO.

Comment: I'd agree with Wouter J. Unless the suggestion is **very** drastically bad, "improve" should not fail the audit.

Comment: Right, then I definitely retract my dupe vote. I edited your post to make it clearer that you failed a suggested edit audit because you clicked approve.

Comment: For reference, here's the audit in question: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1627279 Looking at the edit, wanting to "improve" an edit like that when you see that is *perfectly* acceptable; the audit system is the one in the wrong here.

Comment: The suggested edit audits are completely auto-generated; I guess the devs didn't take into account that they *could* be showing you edit-worthy posts (even with an obviously wrong edit suggestion).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'd say that for the *majority* of edits that should be rejected it would be appropriate to "improve" them and uncheck "helpful".  It's very rare that an edit, regardless of whether it's good or bad, doesn't leave *something* left in the post that could be made better.

Comment: See also: ["I failed a review audit by clicking Improve"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168689/i-failed-a-review-audit-by-clicking-improve)

Comment: @BradLarson ok, but notice the "Suggested edit was helpful" option didn't show up! this is a bug.

Comment: @jackJoe I don't think it's that clear cut. I find the argument in animuson's answer to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169580/186991) (which this is marked as a duplicate of) pretty compelling.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist thanks for that link. I can see this is a recent issue, I hope they follow animuson's suggestion or a way to improve not approving it. I might have also (as I do in other cases) click on the answer to edit it ouside the review context, and reject it under review and then edit it. I'll do that from now on until this bug is sorted.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The problem is that's only a valid option of if you know it's an audit.  If it's not an audit and there aren't already 2 reject votes then if you reject it the suggested edit will prevent you from editing the post.  Any time the workflow for an audit is different from the workflow for a regular edit there is a problem.

Comment: @jackJoe - Right, the fundamental issue here is that clicking "improve" on a suggested edit audit instantly fails the audit. We're using Lance's question about this (one of the duplicates of this one) as the canonical feature request here, which is why I closed this to point to that. I agree that this is an issue, and is tripping up good reviewers.

Comment: @BradLarson et all: nice one, thanks for the help and comments, and let's hope it gets fixed soon.