# Review Audit: highly upvoted but closed question

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I did some First Post Reviews today and eventually got this question as an audit
[C++ What optimizations do compilers still struggle with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305586/c-what-optimizations-do-compilers-still-struggle-with)

It has 20 upvotes but it's (rightly) closed as not constructive.

I wanted to flag it as "primarily opinion based" but when I clicked on flag, I failed the audit:
[image: image of failed audit]

Since I'm still somewhat new to reviewing I what to make sure I get it right in the future. Is this audit defective or was flagging actually the wrong approach?

Comment: The audit is definitely defective.

Comment: **+1** I think I failed that a few days ago by daring to try and comment.

Comment: I probably would have failed that audit too. Good thing I don't do reviews, I guess.

Comment: looking at it...

Comment: an excellent case to support recent feature request to deal with incorrectly picked audits: [Review audits and “I understand” button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188780/165773)

Comment: Using such controverse close candidates as audits is perverse. Possibility to close questions which were asked before new rules were applied keeps me away from close votes queue.

Comment: Probably don't need manual feedback to detect closed questions, @gnat.

Comment: @Shog9 well as an example, with [fix that crap button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790/165773 "suggested here"), that particular bug would be discovered earlier and with less meta hassle - just note [comment above](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189339/review-audit-highly-upvoted-but-closed-question?noredirect=1#comment584387_189339) "I think I failed that a few days ago by daring to try and comment". The smoother is bug reporting the faster is their detection and fix

Comment: How come such an old post appear in the First Posts review (even if it's an audit)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed and rolled out in build 2013.7.18.862. Closed questions are now excluded from known good post audits in the first posts review queue.

Comment: Can you tell us what the change was?