# Contribute review test questions

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

I really like the random tests when reviewing, but I find them too easy to spot now, and they don't really cover all possibilities where somebody could create a bad approval.

### Feature Proposal

I propose that a new feature that allows users with a very high reputation to create new tests that can then be approved by consensus of high rep users.  This can be either integrated into the review screen, or added as a separate section to the top nav bar that appears after the required reputation is reached.

[image: Audit submission and review ui]

When submitting an audit you include the following:

- Audit Type: Suggested Edits, First Posts, etc...
- Post Title,
- Post
- [For Edits] Changed Title
- [For Edits] Changed Post
- Response for Rejection
- Response for incorrect Approval

Like a close vote, an audit is approved by multiple high rep users.

### Possible New Test Ideas

- A test where somebody takes a correct answer and makes it incorrect through a minor change.  There was an answer I was reviewing that was very complicated where the incrementor was moved, and I wasn't sure how that effected the answer.
- A more subtle change of meaning of a sentence:  There are some very radical audit tests where the text is defaced, but what if somebody rewrites a sentence to change the very meaning?  For example, *"How do I assign a function to a variable?"* versus *"How do variables get assigned by a function?"* look very similar, but mean something different.  This might be an especially high risk when somebody is correcting posts by people who speak English as a second language.
- Bad formatting (I've run across this more than once):  Somebody reformats some code, but actually makes it worse because they didn't see a closing parenthesis or tag.

Comment: Also, you haven't seen close vote audits yet. Some of them are *hard*. Like, *really hard*.

Comment: All this proves is that you do regular reviews and are paying attention. Any one with any sense can tell it's an audit after reviewing for a while. You're basically saying I can tell this is an audit when I look at it, that means you're paying attention and look, that is what the audit says you're doing..

Comment: @Undo what rep do we need for close vote audits?

Comment: @Skippy 3k. Close vote privilege, in the CV queue. Currently 64k-ish items. Come help us!

Comment: @Skippy, it's a very superficial level of paying attention to catch an audit.  It is a "blink" response at this point.  I need a greater detail of attention to catch when somebody has rewrote code to turn a correct answer incorrect.

Comment: @undo, I better answer some questions then :)

Comment: @DanielGimenez I always read what I suspect is an audit. If you don't then you're NOT really paying attention then, are you? I was being tongue in cheek in my previous comment

Comment: @Skippy: Then it's another reason audit questions need be improved: Some of them are so off, it has conditioned me to dismiss them out of hand, creating the possibility of me rejecting a legitimate edit that needs a little work.

Comment: @DanielGimenez if you are dismissing edits out of hand, you are not doing a good review job. I still read everything before hitting a button.

Comment: proposed by Community means that the edit was proposed by someone who is not logged in - it has nothing to do with audits

Comment: It doesn't show "proposed by Community" until *after* you make a decision on the audit. Before that, it looks like a regular low-rep user.

Comment: Also, allow me to scare you a bit: you're right, these review audits *are* embarrassingly easy, but *we still have people who fail them*.

Comment: related: [Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168374/165773) and [Review audits and “I understand” button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188780/165773)

Answer (score 2):

> - Can we submit tests?

Nope.

> - If not

Yes?

> ...can this feature be added?

Nope.

You see, the current random tests do a pretty good job of finding existing human errors.

If we had humans deliberately make mistakes, we would need other humans to review the humans' mistakes to make sure they are bad enough. Then we would need audits to find the bad review-reviewers. See?

Comment: There is no evidence that they do a good job, and personally I've grown accustom to spotting them.  They also test a narrow range of mistakes.

Comment: @Daniel Audits are designed to be easy. They are designed to catch the robo-reviewers.

Comment: If that's the primary purpose then they are fine.  But if they are there to ensure people are paying attention to the detail of a post, then they are not.

Comment: @Undo you are copping it with downvotes for saying it as it is this morning, I gave you another +1