# "I don't agree" button on "STOP! Look and Listen" page

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

Sometimes I fail in review audits that I don't agree with. I guess it's at least the third time where I go back to the post I reviewed and do my vote anyway - the vote I have been blamed for.

[Current example here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3015169). (Unfortunately I don't have the previous examples at hand. I'll extend the list when I stumble upon the next one.)

I've already closed a few of these "why doesn't this feature or that function exists in xy"? In the past, they have been closed as "not constructive". Now they are "opinion based" or "off topic". Sometimes there is a good reason and a valid answer. In most cases there is none. Looking at the answers here, there is none. However, I decided to vote to close this question. It was an audit, I failed, I had to go the question again and vote to close it there as "primarily opinion based".

But I have to press on the "I understand" button. The problem is, *I don't understand*.

(I started to go to the question before I do anything in a review, to discover audits and to *vote safely*. Because I don't agree with many audits. I mean, the audits should be there to discover bad reviewers, not to force people to do workarounds.)

**Proposal**: There should be a "I don't agree" button. Pressing that doesn't just make the audit happy, this would obviously be too easy. It should trigger an "auditor" to check the audit again. It would be nice to get an explanation what I do wrong. Or accept my vote.

**Alternative**: Reviews are democratic. It is expected that reviewers have different opinions. So audits shouldn't blame reviewers to have another opinion. Audits should be very clear and *a vast majority of the reviewers should do the same*. Only such audits could be kind of fair.

The same audits should probably be used to test many reviewers. This way the quality of the audit would also be tested by the community.

Comment: So, if I understand your feature request correctly, when you fail an audit you want a button saying roughly "No, I did not fail this audit, I'm right, damm*t"?

Comment: You already took steps to ensure it won't ever be selected for an audit again (under the current audit selection rules) when you voted to close

Comment: This might be a dup, [Review audits and “I understand” button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188780/182513), the proposals are the same but there are some variations in the details and reasoning.

Comment: @Frédéric: Yes, kind of that.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I did some research to find such a request, but didn't find it. This one is really quite close. Even though it is very very long and it's hard to find the actual point ...

Answer (score 2):

Everyone could press 'I don't agree' so the disagreements should be somehow reviewed.

There should be the possibility to flag audit as invalid, with custom message explaining why exactly you think the audit is invalid, and the flags should be reviewed by high-rep users (say, from 10k points).

Comment: Excerpt from the proposal: "Pressing that doesn't just make the audit happy, this would obviously be too easy. It should trigger an "auditor" to check the audit again."