# How many failed audits are bad audits?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, statistics

Is there any reliable information on what percentage of audit failures are due to bad audits and not the failure of the reviewer?

Comment: Unless people come to complain on meta there is no way at present to know when people think audits are bad

Comment: Maybe if [there was a way to provide feedback on audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790) we'd have some way of quantifying audits people disagree with.

Answer (score 8):

My failure rate is about twenty percent.

For the record, I consider this an acceptable tradeoff, if it means that we're reminding the people who need to be reminded to pay attention.

Comment: You fail one out of five audits?  As a diamond moderator?!  And that's OK?!  I'm *completely* missing something here.

Comment: @John: If I see a post in the queue that is asking if the post should be closed, but there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the post, I will sometimes click the close link to see how other people are voting to close.  The audit mechanism sees this as an attempt to close, and will fail the audit.

Comment: Is there a method I can use to find out my own failure rate? An anecdotal sampling of a few users stats isn't perfect but would at least be the germ of something concrete.

Answer (score -3):

Anecdotal evidence: 100%. Every time I fail an audit I end up right-clicking on the question title, and taking the action that caused me to fail the audit anyway.

Comment: This is accumulating a disturbing number of downvotes and no comments.

Comment: I was going to vote down too when I realised that maybe people misread your answer just like I did, like "all audits are bad 100%". Upon second reading though I realised that you maybe meant that only audits you failed are all bad which makes much better sense (my own rate for that is not 100% but fairly close)