# Review Triage: How to protest against an audit?

Tags: discussion, support, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

This audit in the Review Triage looks like a legitimate question to me ("How to implement an upload progress bar?"). I was about to edit it to improve the English and remove the unnecessary link, thereby failing the audit.

Here's a screenshot, since the question was deleted meanwhile (this being also the reason why [this guideline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168374/bring-a-human-factor-into-review-audit-composition-selection/197484#197484) is not working):

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to protest against an audit? If no, please implement one.

EDIT after some comments:
The question "How to implement an upload progress bar?" is clearly a programming question to me. I wouldn't need any more context; a legitimate answer could be a link to some tutorial. Bottom line: I've seen worse question than this one on StackOverflow!

Back to my original question: Is there a way to *flag* or *protest* or whatever an audit you disagree with?

Comment: Full context: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/10388465 - please take a closer look & see if you can figure out why this absolutely had to be deleted...

Comment: @Shog9: Thanks for the link! I know it was deleted because it came from a spam bot. **But how should I have known this??** Is it part of the reviewer's job to do a thorough research to check if this might come from any weird source?

Comment: you should have known because there was no other content in the post. I didn't follow the link myself, but just looking at your screenshot, after you remove the fluff and the link - there's no "There" there.

Comment: to your edit -- would a Windows progress bar in C++ be useful to someone expecting JavaScript for the web? would an iOS progress bar in Swift help someone writing in VB.NET for Windows?

Comment: I'm not certain if "Eh. I've seen worse." is the right attitude to have whilst reviewing/triaging.

Comment: @Kate Gregory: Since the dreaded example link went to a website, the question was clearly about the web.

Comment: @Arthur Fischer: OK, but what about the attitude when selecting the audits? Shouldn't they be 100% clear?
After reading this thread http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/ I now realize that I'm in good company when failing an audit ;-) For the time being, I will quit reviewing.

Comment: Can you picture ***any*** amount of editing that *you* could do that would bring this question to what is in line with the OP's intent? Do you know the relevant language? Back end technology? Until the OP attempts to fix the question and fill in the relevant information, the question is one that is unclear and unsalvageable by someone else. This isn't something that another user can do to bring it into compliance with the expectations. Alternatively, if you think that it *is* on topic, flag to close it as a duplicate of the relevant question yourself.

Answer (score 12):

While I'm [in full support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790) of a way of disputing audits, that was actually a pretty good audit.

The post was spam, and you should not have edited it. The link went to an Iranian commerce site and had nothing to do with the question asked. Spammers commonly make posts like this, and inject spam links into random words. Some even plagiarize well-written posts to do this. Be very careful of posts with randomly linked words that go to completely unrelated sites.

This was the fourth such post by this particular user, and there had been a dozen others all pointing to that same Iranian site by other accounts. You didn't have that context, but even without it you should have been able to detect that this was possible spam. Even with editing, that question was unsalvageable.

Comment: I did click on that damn link and it did feature a file upload right in the center of the page. I even uploaded a file and there was some sort of animation. What sort of example link would *you* expect? In any case: I was about to delete the link anyway!

Comment: @ThomasLandauer questions on Stack Overflow should be self-sufficient. The content of linked websites does not make a question on-topic. The content of linked websites will change over time.

Answer (score 9):

Without the link, and the "Friends if anyone knows please advise. Thanks." what you have left is an essentially worthless question. Assuming it was on Stack Overflow, what language? What context? (web? phone? Windows? Mac?) What has the person done so far? What trouble are they encountering doing it?

Answer: nothing. This isn't even gimmeh-teh-codez, because there's not enough specification here even for that. It just isn't a question. It's a link container attempting to disguise itself as a question. Removing the link and cleaning up the grammar is pointless, because after that there will be nothing left.

Depending on where the link leads, you might flag as spam. Otherwise it just needs to go away.