# What is the correct way to report a questionable audit?

Tags: feature-request, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed a triage queue audit today, and received a two-day review ban.  This was my first failed audit in (I think) weeks.

But this is not a protest if audit ban injustice.  Rather, I would like to know how to properly report a bad audit.  I checked meta and found a question talking about this at length and proposing such methods ([Review audits and "I understand" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790)), but cannot find any confirmation on how it works today.

The audit I failed was a question about an application automatically operating in the background.  I flagged it as Off-topic: General Hardware/Software: 
 [Disable Xcode 9 app automatically building in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289380/disable-xcode-9-app-automatically-building-in-background)

Comment: Personally I'd chill out about this and enjoy your weekend away from reviews.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't usually review on weekends anyway. I'd still like to know if there's something to do when you get a weird audit question.

Comment: Bring it up on the per-site meta, usually. Explain clearly why you think it's a bad audit, and ask for how it should have been reviewed- It could be that you misinterpreted the audit rather than it being questionable. Even the best of us can do this, after all! If it's questionable, people will agree and say so more than likely.

Comment: In this specific case, that question isn't off-topic. The rules say "_Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.**_" (emphasis mine). XCode is used primarily for programming so that question is on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, I missed the faq Meta post that answers this:

"The [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work/157172#157172) says If you encounter a bad audit, post it on the child meta tagged support disputed-review-audits to draw attention to it, containing a link to either the audit task or the post, and why you disagree with the audit"