# Review Audits confusing Questions and Answers

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, review, review-audits

Failed another high quality [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2528083) (for trying to [make a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188885/172958)).

However, I discovered something interesting. It would be a good idea if the the there was a match between question and answer.

[image: Screen shot of review audit message]

Comment: "upovoting"... :)

Comment: thnx Eugene, wasn't especially earth shattering, just noticed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed the text so it says `post` instead of `answer`. Should be rolled out soon.

Comment: I know it's not a big deal, just noticed it, thnx.. still not sure what to do about commenting on posts I'm reviewing and failing audits.. BUT that's a separate issue

Comment: Eh, don't worry about failing a review audit or three.  Not important as long as you're not failing most of them.

Comment: @Joe I have failed three high quality review audits, each time for wanting to make a comment.. I comment on a good proportion of the posts I review