# Quick! Everyone upovote this!

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, spelling

I just failed an audit, just like every month. I'm not here to complain, though - I saw this:

> ### STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even ***upovoting***.

Upovoting? New feature? Does it refer to the action of upvoting a post when a unicorn is in your backyard eating a waffle?

> ### upovote <sup>-v</sup>
>
> 1. The action of upvoting a post on a Stack Exchange website when a unicorn is eating a waffle in your backyard.
> 2. The action of upvoting after seriously considering downvoting.

Seriously, though, it's a typo. Could it be fixed? Please?

Comment: good spot, that's one unassuming o.

Comment: I upovoted your comment.

Comment: Well, if you're filing this one, I'm going to go file the one-pixel typo bug I've got lying around.

Comment: I upovoted this before I read the body. But only because I knew I could remove it within 5 minutes. ;)

Comment: Congratulations, you just got #1 on Google for [upovote](https://www.google.com/search?q=upovote).

Comment: @AndrewBarber =SUBSTITUTE(AndrewBarber.post,"up voted","upovoted") -- there. Fixed it for you.

Comment: Am I the only one who missed the "o" in the tittle on the first read? I almost down-voted just to be contrary...

Comment: @jmac Yup; you really *did* fix it, apparently! ;)

Comment: Hey! I [found it first](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189179/review-audits-confusing-questions-and-answers#comment583799_189179) ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Excel > JQuery. The proof is in the pudding.

Comment: @jmac mmm... I love pudding...

Comment: What is it called it when I upvote something as a waffle eats my unicorn in the backyard?

Comment: Asad, I don't know. But if you upovote something as a waffle eats your unicorn, I believe you win the internet.

Comment: @Asad It's called a big-waffle-o-voting.

Comment: downovote, not enough freehand red circles `</joke>` +1

Comment: I find it odd there are 4 downovotes on this.

Comment: I upovoted it, but some usoers probaboly just downovoted to condroadict the tiotle.

Comment: @Doorknob Is that a cry for help?

Comment: @Undo More like a croy for hoelp.

Comment: And yes, I saw that unicorn eating the waffle. +1 =D

Comment: @Doorknob Oooh, I see what yoou did there!

Comment: Ok, now that the joke has run its course (I hope), can you give it a correct title now please?

Comment: @AaronBertrand no

Comment: failed review audit spelling fail

Comment: You're a drama-o-queen! ;)

Comment: This makes me think of *o-matic* -- maybe a reference to robo-reviewing after all? ;-)

Comment: How do you keep failing audits? I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Fixed, should be available in your *failed* review audits so-o-on (like 2013.7.30.xyz)

Comment: Seems like you have a sneaky 0 making its way into your username too