# STOP! Look and Listen

Tags: feature-request, support, review, vote-to-close, disputed-review-audits

Whenever I review Close Votes, I sometimes stumble upon something that I don't think should be closed, but just to make sure I haven't missed something, I press the "Close" button to see how many people have actually voted that something is e.g. off-topic or what is going on.

Unfortunately, this method is faulty, because from time to time I'll be met with this message which I'm sure we're all familiar with.

[image: STOP! Look and Listen]

And all of a sudden, I feel bad and feel like I've done something wrong, even though I haven't actually voted to close anything, I just wanted to peak.

Therefore, I have a question and a request:

**Question:** Are those times where I apparently *don't pass the test* getting recorded? If I keep using this method, will it eventually have some effect on my voting?

**Request:** Can we not make the error message show up until reviewers have clicked "Vote to close"? In the dialog, it shows many people have voted. Just adding random votes in here will only further my confusion to the close reason, but not having any votes in there will also be "suspicious". Exactly how this can be changed, I don't know; I just know that I don't like getting told to stop and listen for no reason...sob.

Comment: Why are you letting other people's close votes influence how *you* feel about the question?

Comment: I am not, but I acknowledge that I can miss something. If I'm looking at a question and I can't see a reason why it should be closed, either I'm missing something or whoever is voting to close is missing something. I'm trying to determine which it is. If only one person has voted to close and I can't see anything wrong, I'll happily keep it open. On the other hand, if multiple people are voting to close and I don't understand why, naturally that's something I'll have to examine in depth.

Comment: This is not limited to pressing close, the same thing happens if you attempt to comment, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188885/clicking-add-comment-fails-review-audit), which IMO is even worse than this issue...

Comment: Yes those failures are recorded and enough of them will cause automatic review ban for two days. When it happens you can ask to lift the ban manually, either here or by flagging one of your own posts choosing Other and pleading your case.

Comment: The workaround everyone uses is to just open the actual question in a new tab. This is necessary because the user interface of the review queues is terrible, littered with landmines and lacking enough context to allow you to make useful decisions. Perhaps eventually, the team will decide that it needs to be fixed. Maybe once the Android app is officially released.

Comment: Also sometimes the question they show for review audit are one that should be closed. No way to identify whether this is a review audit or not.

Comment: This question has been closed as a duplicate, even though the duplicate question doesn't answer my question. So would somebody mind doing so? Will these failed tests affect my voting abilities?

Comment: The only thing that can happen due to failed audits is a short timed review ban, blocking you from accessing the review queues. In this case you still can vote to close questions you encounter in other ways.

Comment: Thank you, @RalZarek.