# How do I know if I've failed, passed, or even had an audit?

Tags: support, review-audits

I spend most of my time on the culture and religion Stack Exchange sites.  I'd like to think I've done my fair share of reviewing.

Here on M.SO, I keep seeing questions about 'failing audits.'  I can't for the life of me remember actually even seeing if I've *been* audited!

So, three questions:

1. Is automated Review Auditing part of all graduated sites, or just SO?
2. How do I know if I had one?
3. How do I know if I passed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Audits are not enabled on most sites. We enable audits on a site-by-site basis, depending on traffic and need.
2. You will be told that you have passed/failed an audit as soon as you have taken an action on the audit item.
3. See #2.

An example of a passed audit would look something like:

[image: passed an audit!]

A failed audit would look like:

[image: oh noes! I failed an audit - boo hoo, hiss]

Comment: Tsk tsk... no failed audit screenshot?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - It needs to happen before I can take a screen shot of it, you know? JK - this is on my local box where _every_ review is an audit.

Comment: Hmm.. I always thought the "STOP!" is in red.

Comment: Should play sounds and blink too.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - it might be. I was using the MSO theme at the time. It probably looks different on SO and the other sites.

Comment: @Wooble - [meta-tag:feature-request] (and don't forget to ask for the window to shake as well)

Comment: @Wooble that would be a great way to lose some rep, yeah. :)

Comment: @Oded [no red on the main site either](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192395/152859).

Comment: Failing an audit - alarms should sound and a hand comes out of the monitor and slap you.

Comment: .. or shuts your computer down.

Comment: Yeah, definitely alarms, and maybe the screen should flash red and white, since the failed audit text is so light handed and non judgemental.