# You didn´t pass this test - bug

Tags: bug, review-audits

I think I found a small bug. When getting an audit question, I might want to look around in the comments of that question, to see what others think, before flagging it or just clicking the "Nothing to do" button. When I do this, I'm already told that I didn't pass the test. I think this is wrong. I'm just trying to do the job as well as I can.

Additionally, I think that getting an audit question every third time is highly annoying.

Comment: Just found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2721962

Comment: If you pressed the flag button on a great post, you will fail the audit. Other people should not influence your reviews.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188885/clicking-add-comment-fails-review-audit

Comment: @DaveChen But looking for the comments left from other users is not what robo-reviewers do. The audits are for stopping robo-reviewers, not punishing normal users.

Comment: OK, it is a duplicate. I did search for the duplicate but couldn't find it.