# Why are comments now disabled on the review queue?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, review

Today, on C.SE, I reviewed some 'Late Answers' and First Posts.  I was not even near my daily vote limit.  And yet, I was given a message that said

> comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews

It seems I was not the only one either: [Why are comments now disabled on "first posts" reviews?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/why-are-comments-now-disabled-on-first-posts-reviews)

The workaround, of course, was simply to go back and provide the guidance - but was this a design or a bug?  If it is design, why would you want to discourage the feedback? Especially with first posts, there is often a high percentage of 'didn't read the FAQ' usage, which can best be addressed by gently providing guidance. (e.g. "Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question" or "This reads like a comment" or "This really isn't on-topic here - can I suggest you checkout our [faq]" etc...)  Timely first post guidance goes a long way towards making good users.

If it was a bug, was other functionality silently rolled out?

Comment: You beat me to it.  This seems very counter-productive.  The odds of a first time user needing constructive, friendly guidance are quite high, compared to experienced users. Commenting and pointing to Meta posts is a valuable tool for those of us that want to help newcomers. I'm very curious about why this would be disabled.

Comment: Many, perhaps even most, first time OPs need help formulating & clarifying their question. This is a very unfortunate & counter-productive change.

Comment: I am with you here. Did a first post review - and the answer was no where related to the question. I didn't know what to do, as the commenting was disabled. So, I simply down-voted the answer. And apparently, I failed the review. Sigh.

Comment: I've been opening the post in a new tab and commenting anyway.  Very time-consuming, but I don't see any other way to actually be helpful. Hopefully this gets reversed quickly.

Comment: @Somya then it's a bad audit, and not because you were supposed to comment

Comment: To (partially) address your closing question, `comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews` suggests that this was a deliberate change (not a bug), since "reviews" seems unlikely to have ended up in that list by mere happenstance. Though why anyone would want to deliberately maim the review interface in that way is beyond me...

Comment: When did this change?

Comment: Another example: in addition to flagging the answer, I almost *always* add a comment to link-only answers that asks the user to summarize the link's contents. I'm not sure why such behavior is intentionally discouraged, especially since [link-only answers themselves are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/218097), and I've been led to believe that comments asking for a summary are welcome.

Comment: @JanDvorak - What other option did I have? Get rid of the answer. But that would mean posting a blank answer :P

Comment: @Somya Presumably you could have flagged the answer as "Not an answer" or "Other", and described the problem. If it was a review audit, I believe simply clicking "flag" is enough. You wouldn't actually have to complete the flag dialog.

Comment: this looks like (a pretty lame imNSho) attempt to salvage "known good" audits in this queue, which [fail miserably](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197823/165773 "discussed here") if one can comment. Next (lame) steps will likely be disabling flagging and edits, thus making whole review a victim of wrongly picked audit strategy. Why doesn't SE team consider keeping only "known bad" audits in FP / LA queues, simply escapes my mind

Comment: Just went through a dozen reviews. Do not like this. At all. Cannot explain in a comment why you are voting to close. Cannot explain to a new user where to look for pointers to improve their posts. Cannot explain to late answers that their answer is a complete duplicate of another answer. What a horrible design choice.

Comment: Judging by [Shog's edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/198951/4), it looks like this is a bug and not an intentional change.  Hopefully someone from the dev or community team can chime in and let us know the status

Comment: @Shog9 [meta-tag:status-planned] then?

Comment: I've also observed this on Code Review, so it's not an SO-only thing.

Comment: Facing same issue since morning, working fine before weekend.

Comment: This wasn't intentional, but not entirely surprising.  I'll take a look as soon as I can.

Comment: @gnat let's not get carried away.  It's a bug.

Comment: @BenCollins can't wait to see it fixed

Comment: @BenCollins it's rarely that I am glad to hear that something is a bug, but in this case, I really am

Comment: FWIW, I tried to talk him into fixing this by just getting rid of comments in /review/first-posts, but he had a better idea, @gnat. Damn clever devs...

Comment: @Shog9 painting in my imagination apocalyptic pictures of getting rid of comments _at all_ ([would that make George happy?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180325/165773 "a way to handle the explosion of comments on Stack Overflow")). BTW can't tell that this bug affected me personally; I am doing most of review related actions by opening the post in a separate tab anyway :)

Comment: Looks like it's now fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What happened here was that I set an incorrect flag on the review views which led to commenting being disabled in places where it shouldn't have been.  This has been corrected now.

Comment: So, I know common practice on MSO is to make snarky comments about our evil overlords and such - but every now and then you need to hear it plain.  We who use your work every day really, really appreciate the hard work that goes into making this one of the best dang places on the Internet.  Thank you for your service.

Comment: [This bug](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11148/43351) on Maths.SE seems intimately related. I can confirm that the issue has gone away on duplicate reviews (in the duplicate tab); however, it still occurs on "first post" reviews (below the question), and possibly also on "low quality" reviews. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Can you provide a link to a specific review exhibiting this problem?

Comment: [This one](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/104230). Click "show 6 more comments" to show the dreaded text. [This one](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/103921) from the Low Quality queue originally instigated my post.

Comment: Ah.  In both cases, the *behavior* is correct, but the text is not.  The correct text would be something like "disabled for review".  This will be fixed soon in a build near you.

Comment: @BenCollins Excellent; when the appropriate time comes, could you be as kind as to answer the [question on meta.maths.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11148/43351) and mark it status-completed? Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: (Sorry to bother you again, but it turns out my report of success for duplicate reviews was pre-emptive -- I have encountered it again today, but it doesn't show up when visiting the review page afterwards.)