# Can we (please) have the ability to comment while reviewing restored?

Tags: feature-request

Related:  [Why are comments now disabled on “first posts” reviews?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198951/why-are-comments-now-disabled-on-first-posts-reviews)

In the question linked to above, Affable Geek asked [the same question I did over at C.SE](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/why-are-comments-now-disabled-on-first-posts-reviews): Why was this changed and was it intentional.

I don't know if what I'm asking here is implied on those questions, but just to be sure, ***I'd like to officially put in a feature request to have this ability restored***.

I spend most of my time on various S.E. sites reviewing instead of asking and answering.  I'm not sure what was behind the decision to remove this functionality, but as someone who spends most of my time trying to help new users, offer constructive guidance, and [help make StackExchange (and thereby the Internet) a better place](http://lifehacker.com/5950386/im-jeff-atwood-founder-of-stack-exchange-and-this-is-how-i-work), the inability to leave comments seems extremely counter-productive.

For new users, the most helpful thing we can do to help them improve their posts is to provide polite, helpful, constructive comments in the spirit of the [Summer of Love](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/).  (Which, IMO is or should be an endless summer...)  The inability do do this gains us nothing, and severely hampers our ability to help.

This new restriction also seems a bit odd to me in light of all the Meta posts asking about how we can encourage (or force)people to comment when down-voting.  I realize it's a bad idea to ***force*** people to comment when down-voting, and I wouldn't suggest that, but the point is, all of these people recognize that simply voting down a question without leaving a constructive comment does absolutely nothing to help the person whose post is being down-voted.  I may be wrong, but I thought that the purpose for having the community moderate is to

> Help your fellow members learn to use the site and raise the quality
> of Q&A by:
>
> - Evaluating new posts
> - Voting to close or reopen questions
> - Reviewing suggested edits

It's awful hard to be helpful when you have to [jump through hoops to provide helpful comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198951/why-are-comments-now-disabled-on-first-posts-reviews#comment631233_198951).

I ask the StackExchange team to please consider restoring our ability to comment while reviewing.

Comment: Based on the tags of the possible duplicate question, the lack of ability to comment is a bug (and the bug tag was were added by a SE Employee, so it would appear to be a legit tag).  I'm interpreting that to mean this is not a function that was intentionally removed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Thanks  I didn't see Shog9's edit. I was still thinking it was intentional because of the wording as Mac said in his comment on that post.  Either way, I just wanted to be sure that if Affable's post wasn't seen as a request to change this, that someone made an official feature request.  if this post gets closed, that's OK by me as long as it gets reviewed by the SE team.

Comment: I want the feature restored as much as anyone.  Who knows if it was actually intentional or not, but if it wasn't, then the bug tag would then suggest they made an error in how they implemented a new feature (or something was rolled out before it was ready).  My point is that it is counter productive to have multiple questions open on the same issue, especially bugs.  I think the content here would be much better served as an answer on that post than a separate feature request.