# Was this a false alarm?

Tags: discussion, bug, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

While doing a First Posts review I came across a one which was a [one liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18953383/1309352), code. Which I assume is inappropriate by SO standards ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18292861/1309352), for those who [can view](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)). The user's avatar was in gray, no names, reps, badges, and the text below the post which said

> comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews

was a hyperlink therefore I just clicked on it, to see what would happen. And what I got was:

> **STOP! Look and Listen.**
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You
>   didn't pass.** Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality
>   post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but
>   please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the
>   guidance above.

Wasn't it a false alarm and a misjudgment?

And honestly, I was thinking of a either editing it or see if a flag was appropriate.

One more thing, if that was a "high quality post" then why was the post(linked above) deleted by the moderator?

Comment: Broken audits are the reason I won't review until [a feedback mechanism is put in place](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/191262#191262). I think the current solution of "bad audit" => "meta post" is a bunch of noisy red tape that really only fixes some potholes when the road needs to be completely repaved, and the extra steps involved prevent the problem from being seen for as bad as it is.

Comment: @jball To be quite honest, I'm kind of getting tired of people saying things like that. This *isn't* a constant issue. In fact, the current success rate on First Posts audits is 89% of 5371 over the past 30 days. That's just under 600 failed audits in a month, of which only a small percentage would be considered "bad audits." You're only robbing the site of potentially valuable reviews by being afraid of a *chance* of getting a bad review audit.

Comment: The "comments disabled" thing is a bug, [and we're fixing it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198951/why-are-comments-now-disabled-on-the-review-queue). We're also addressing the issue of comments inappropriately failing reviews while we're at it.

Comment: Your "one liner" link points to one of your deleted answers. One which, honestly, looks fine. Am confused.

Comment: @Won't It's not fine, as it doesn't answer the question given.

Comment: Regarding the accident described in this question - it's rather trivial to say, but I can't reproduce it (and I just got myself audit on First Posts). Shouldn't the warning be triggered by the _action_ on the post? If so, clicking on the link to check it definitely won't count.

Comment: Repeating myself: if the text of the audit failed message wasn't so harsh, people wouldn't be here on meta complaining every time they see it.