# Site review shows me a disabled "add comment" link, and tells me I need a reputation of at least 50

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, site-evaluation

I was looking at a question shown for the [*Site Self-Evaluation*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval/3945) on *English Language Learners*, and noticed the "add comment" link was disabled because I needed at least 50 points of reputation.

[image: screenshot]

As the screenshot shows, my reputation is more than 50.

The link should not appear, if commenting is not allowed, or I should be allowed to comment.

Comment: What is this "site review?"

Comment: @Doorknob It's the _Site Self-Evaluation_ review that sometimes appears on Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known deficiency](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11148/add-comment-requires-50-reputation-in-review) with the text of the comment link which should be corrected soon.  Also, see [Why are comments now disabled on the review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198951/why-are-comments-now-disabled-on-the-review-queue)