# The low quality queue doesn't believe I have enough rep to comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, review, low-quality-posts

When reviewing an answer in the low quality queue the question doesn't believe that I have enough reputation to comment.

> [image]

I can't remember if commenting on the post not actually being reviewed was ever allowed?

Comment: I am pretty sure commenting in the LQP queue was never allowed.

Comment: I'm now seeing the same thing when reviewing a first post in Code Review.

Comment: Has anything changed for you?  I was just in the LPQ on SO and it appeared as if I was permitted to comment (although I ddin't)

Comment: I've noticed the same at [wordpress.se]

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11148/add-comment-requires-50-reputation-in-review, but we'll leave this one open as the bug of reference on meta.  This problem should go away soon, and I'll come back and give an actual answer afterwards.

Comment: @BenCollins The bug has been solved. It now states "comments disabled for reviews".

Comment: @hjpotter92 thank you very much for letting me know that.  It's actually something of a trick to verify things if diamond mods or employees have special privileges (which they do in this case).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Site review shows me a disabled "add comment" link, and tells me I need a reputation of at least 50](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199576/site-review-shows-me-a-disabled-add-comment-link-and-tells-me-i-need-a-reputa)