# Is it bad practice to look at the specific reason for closing a question before voting?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

I was going through the [close vote queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/) today and I ran into something that hadn't happened to me before

It is my general practice to, upon seeing a new question in the queue, briefly review the question for any obvious faults, overall quality of the question, and whether or not it fits the general description of the close vote, then click the "Close" button and look at the specific reason specified for closing the question before reviewing the question in more detail if necessary

Is that bad practice?

I ask this because today I ran into one of the audits to make sure users are paying attention to the questions they're reviewing. Upon first glance it looked like a legitimate question, I had no inclination to close it for the "off topic" reason provided, but as always I clicked the "Close" button to check out the specific reason given for voting to close it (thus failing the audit). There must be some reason for the tester fails me when I click "Close" as opposed to "Vote to close"

**Edit**

Of the people who disagree with the LowerClassOverflowian's answer (or anyone else), does someone want to provide an answer? I'd like to hear some other people's input

Also, [this proposition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223613/215485) seems to be what I think should happen

Comment: Middle click on the quesions title to open it in a new tab, then you can see whatever you want without getting this problem.

Comment: [Similar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223581/dont-fail-audit-right-away-when-improving-a-suggested-edit#comment728716_223581)

Answer (score 2):

It's bad practice to vote based on how other people are voting. Don't do that.

Read the question yourself, and then if you decide it should be closed, click to ***close*** it, and then select your reason why and then click ***vote to close***. It doesn't matter what other people chose. It's your vote.

As you have learned, once you click on ***close***, *before you even officially voted to close*, the audit will fail you *(if it should have remained open)*. I don't know the exact reasons for this, but I like that it works that way, since it will hopefully stop people from doing what you just recently starting doing... in that you're wanting to see how other people are voting.

1. It's your vote. No one else's.
2. It's your review. No one else's.
3. Assume everyone else is an idiot, so you don't want their opinion anyways.

I know you're not really voting based on other people's vote, but some people probably do.  However, subliminally, it probably is affecting your vote.

You are however, being curious. *Curiosity killed the cat. Curiosity failed you an audit.*

Comment: I disagree. *Especially* for newly privileged users, seeing what other people think of a question can be a good learning experience. Even now at >10k, I'll *still* click into the close dialog if I see a pending close vote on a question, just to see what it is and leave a comment (or edit) if I think it might prevent more CVs.