# Looks like it could be a dupe to me

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, review-audits

I recently failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4592636) when I clicked "Close". I did so because it looked like a very possible duplicate of the suggested answer in the comments ([this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1/20276908#20276908))

Now, I'm not an iOS developer so maybe that is the problem or maybe I'm too tired. But I can't see how this is a valid failed audit. I have made a mistake or two in the past so maybe I did so here. If so, could someone please explain or should this have been an acceptable action that I tried to take.

My pride wasn't destroyed too much from failing the audit. Mostly I want to know if I missed something.

Comment: Yes, you missed something.  At the very top you'd see: `Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully`

Comment: @devnull I did see that and recognized that it isn't spam. However, does this mean that I can't vote to close it for another reason?

Comment: The audits are picked automatically; sometimes the system gets it wrong. Don't sweat it, visit the post directly and cast your dupe vote and it won't be picked again.

Comment: Hmm.. I agree.  Perhaps not the best of audits, yet again.  Who said computers were smarter?

Comment: @devnull The computers did.  And since they're smarter, we believed them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the response. I understand that they are picked by a computer and not perfect. The new question that has been brought to light is, should I only vote to close if it's spam when the system says it has detected it as such?

Answer (score 4):

Audits are not chosen by people, they are merely chosen by the system based on whether or not they meet certain criteria, such as "have no votes to close", "has no flags", "has more than X upvotes", "has no downvotes", etc.  This post met those criteria.  It could of course possibly be a duplicate.  If you feel that it is, go to the question and vote accordingly; if you do, the question won't ever be provided as an audit, as those criteria won't be met.

Comment: That's helpful. I didn't know how they were picked. Anyway, the question remains, when it says that the system detected it as spam, does that mean that I should **only** vote to close if I think it's spam?

Comment: @codeMagic You shouldn't vote to close at *all* if you think it's spam.  You should flag it as spam if you think it's spam.

Comment: Yes, my wording was wrong, sorry. I mean, if the system says it thinks its spam but I do not, should I never vote to close for any reason through the review queue? Just trying to understand how the system works as far as that goes.

Comment: @codeMagic No.  If it's not spam but still close worthy, vote to close it.

Comment: Which is what I did but failed. Again, I'm ok if it was just a computer glitch but I wanted to make sure I took the right course of action and that the computer just screwed it up.

Comment: Yes. It was the audit system that got it wrong. I think there's a proposal somewhere for making it only fail if you actually submit the form, not just click the button, which could extend to not failing if you vote as dup.

Comment: @bjb568 ok, thanks. I know that is something I posted about awhile back ([not failing until committing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223581/dont-fail-audit-right-away-when-improving-a-suggested-edit)). I hope you are right about the last part.