# How to contest a review ban?

Tags: support, comments, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button) suggests a button to contest a failed audit and [this other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196685/review-audit-commenting-on-good-questions-discouraged) as well as a few others agree on the fact that sometimes the audit system consider a comment on a perfect post as a negative action.

But this button feature has not been added, so what is actually the way to contest a failed audit, especially if it has led to a ban of the review queues ?

I just failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13693330) because I wanted to give the author my opinion on an easier way to achieve what he wanted to do, but it didn't directly answer his question and wasn't therefore a valid answer, which is why I wanted to put it in a comment.

Since this is an automatic ban, it's probably usual that it bans people for wrong reasons, then what's the usual way to report those cases to human beings ?

Comment: "How to contest a review ban ?" You just did.

Comment: @Yannis Indeed, but I don't know if posting here is the way of doing it, hence the question.

Comment: Just report on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits). If you have a valid case, a ♦ moderator can lift the ban.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You contest a review ban by posting your question about the issue, together with a link to the disputed review, **on the meta of the site where you've received your review ban.**

In your case, that's Meta Stack Overflow.