# Don't let users comment on review audit questions

Tags: feature-request, comments, review-audits

When reviewing reopen votes, I was given [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844764/when-is-a2bb2a-a-power-of-2) as a review audit. I [commented](http://puu.sh/aoEkf/6442ed5b19.png), nonsensically, that I didn't understand why the question was closed as primarily-opinion based, as that's what the review audit showed the close reason as. I deleted the comment, but nonetheless, I shouldn't have been allowed to comment while being misinformed.

When we're "lying" to users about the status of a question in a review audit, comments should either be disallowed or not copied over to the question itself.

Comment: It seems they changed the commenting-on-audit behavior. It used to be that  [clicking “Add comment” failed review audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188885/) for "known-good" posts,  with no comment being actually posted. Apparently, in your case the comment   got posted.  I'd guess this is a bug.

Comment: Let's just remove the comment button on reopen reviews?

Comment: This is [status-completed]. See my answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307603/349538).