# Do let users comment on review audit questions (sometimes)

Tags: discussion, comments, review-audits

The interaction between auditing and commenting keeps wasting my time. I just had the complementary experience to "[Don't let users comment on review audit questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237018/dont-let-users-comment-on-review-audit-questions)".

Whether the post is good or bad, a comment might still be appropriate, and the system lets you write one. You spend some time finding the right link on meta, checking that nobody's mentioned what you're talking about in another comment or an answer. You write your comment and click "add comment." And the system says "Haha! This was just a test!" and throws your well-researched, carefully written words into a black hole.

If the post was a good one, so it still exists in the system, the comment should be added to it: I don't think this has the mildly negative effect used to justify [not counting votes made during audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242840/votes-on-review-audit-are-not-placed-on-the-question). If the post was a bad one and has already been deleted, the system knows that no comments can be posted so it should end the audit as soon as the user tries to add a comment, rather than letting them waste their time commenting on a post that doesn't even exist any more.