# "This is an audit"

Tags: bug, review-audits

I've tried to comment a spam-like post politely (before I vote to del).

It turned out that it was a long deleted post, and the review was an audit. The software warned me.

I don't know, is it intentional? I think, reviewers shouldn't have any option to find out, if a review is an audit or not.

[Here](https://serverfault.com/review/low-quality-posts/315674) is the review audit entity link.

[image]

Comment: I think by bothering to take the time to comment on the answer you've already passed the audit. Audits are largely targeting robo-reviewers.

Comment: The problem was that many *nice* users left an informative comment before they clicked recommend deletion to explain (at length) why the post was so bad it needed to be deleted. However, leaving comment was seen as an *Looks OK* action which make them fail the audit. As a compromise the system now simply reveals it is an audit to save time and frustration of the *nice* users. I personally have never seen that warning.

Comment: related: [This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288047/839601) and [Clicking “Add comment” fails review audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188885/165773)

Comment: Note: [detecting audits is not illicit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310885/would-a-userscript-to-determine-whether-a-review-is-an-audit-be-illegal).

Comment: Stop being nice to obvious spammers.  And please visit my website http://enlargeurpenix.com

Comment: @Wont :-) I wasn't, it was dubious case. Finally the deciding argument for the del vote was that the user had only 1rep (note: if also the mods had found the case obvious, the account had been deleted, but it wasn't).