# Bad review audit

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

On Stack Overflow, I was tested on this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17615602

I only wanted to comment on the good answer asking for further details and an explanation with code, but I failed the audit because it mistook that for a negative review.

This link ([What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)) says it's recommended to report bad audits here.

Comment: *This link say it's recommended to post here reclamation.* I didn't read that. Failing just one review audit doesn't do any harm, so just move on. There is no point in a reclamation of any kind.

Comment: And I didn't read anything abusive. What exactly is abusive in your opinion?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306916/is-it-consensus-that-commenting-should-not-lead-to-failing-review-audits

Comment: @PatrickHofman "If you encounter a bad audit, post it on the child meta tagged supportdisputed-review-audits to draw attention to it, containing a link to either the audit task or the post, and why you disagree with the audit"

Comment: Okay, but this is not the child meta. And I am sorry, but disputing such audits is pointless. You shouldn't have taken that action (from the review audit point of view. It is just a known problem with them).

Comment: There is nothing to revert or turn back. It can't. They won't.

Comment: @PatrickHofman do not be unpleasant, I try to understand

Comment: Audits are machine-made. They sometimes are wrong. In this case you took the wrong action *for a review (audit)*. Next time you see an excellent post in review, think "hey, this is a weird post for review, it must be an audit".

Comment: And I am not being unpleasant, I just say you are wasting your time.

Comment: yeah, it's been 2 times that I get screwed up and I realize, it is reviewing is a waste of time. definition of "I'm done" it's not clear. I thought to improve the content of the site, I only make me blocked, i'll be back when the system been improved

Comment: Why is this off-topic? That specific audit was on Stack Overflow, but the same thing could happen on other sites. This question is possibly a duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188885/349538), but it's not off-topic.

Comment: Maybe "abusive" is not the word you were actually looking for... I would have said that audit *"sucks donkey balls"*.  It's a very low quality answer with 11 upvotes.  I'd have failed that audit.  Perhaps audits shouldn't consider highly upvoted answers without any code...

Comment: That's a problem with so. bring it into MSO. then only the SO mods can look into it. coz most of the SO mods are not active on MSE.

Comment: @DonaldDuck this is off topic. If the same happens in another site, bring that particular thing to corresponding child meta. **If they have a general problem with some examples, then combine it all and ask it here** because many of the site mods are not active on MSE. Mods can act on bullsh*ts like the above but bringing it here is a noise at all

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to participate in audits, you cannot comment on the posts.  If you do, then you are considered a participant in the post, and you should not be involved in the audit process.

So please choose to either audit a post, or participate in a post, but please don't do both.

If you really feel the need to participate and audit, complete the audit first, then find the question in the site outside the audit system and participate there.

Comment: A common scenario is that you click the question or answer link, open it in a new tab and go from there. Then you'll also see it is an audit and you can take the appropriate review action.

Comment: When i reveiw, i have tree choice : No action needed, I'm done (disable), Skip. "I'm done" become enable if you comment or flag answer. Why we could not comment so ?

Comment: Because in review, commenting means: "Hey, there is something wrong with your post. And this is why...". @GGO