# Another indicator of a review audit: Question has no tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, suggested-edits, review-audits

I have found another indicator that reveals a post to be an audit in the review queue. The question did not show the tags, although they are normally shown. Here is the image(the image is after I passed, but it didn't show the tags before either):

### Review with no tags:

[image: audit with bug]

### Proof it has tags:

[image: proof of tags]

And here is an image of a real review on a question that showed the tags (even though they weren't being changed), which I believe is normal:

### Non-audit review with tags:

[image: expected review]

Obviously, things that indicate that the review is an audit is bad (I have found several, check my previous posts). If someone can please confirm that this is a bug so that it can be fixed?

**EDIT:** This appears to not be a "known-good audit".

Comment: That's something that would be noticed if someone was paying attention. Isn't that the purpose of the audits: to separate those who are paying attention from those who are not?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Maybe. The fact that it didn't seem *right*, because of the noticeable difference in the UI was jarring, and distracted me from reviewing. All the other indicators that I have found, have since been fixed. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156938/169404) is my first post on the subject which goes into a discussion on the **distraction** caused by it.

Comment: Yeah, what George says is true and all, but I can't think of a good reason to *omit* the tags for review audits. I mean, after all, they're actually there, the system just has to display them.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins When I pay attention to reviews, I get banned because of the [broken UI](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191703/169404), much like this.

Comment: Once again, the broken UI **distracts** from the review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.

The tell-tale lack of tags in a review audit will no longer be there, starting in the next build (rev 2013.9.27.1040).