# I still want to edit a vandalizing edit

Tags: discussion, review-audits

The review system flagged me down in an audit for trying to edit a vandalizing edit. The vandalism was trivially undoable (two clicks and delete), and I had an edit in mind anyway - so I was trying to do it quicker without opening the question on another page. I think the review system should only act when your action is finished. In case of an edit, clicking "Edit" doesn't mean you actually did anything just yet!

Shouldn't this misbehavior of the review system be considered a bug, and shouldn't it be fixed?

Comment: IMHO it's better to refuse it and put the reason than to just let "community" refuse it without any written reason.

Comment: look at this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156938/stop-look-and-listen-audit-tricked-me?lq=1 it's similar

Comment: Sigh, it's a dupe and I can't delete it :(

Answer (score 6):

This is the exception, not the rule.

As you say, it as obviously an audit. The first thing you do when you hit an obvious-audit is reject it - the post with a link to the post will still be there. Click it, go edit the post, and move on.

Normally, these vandalism audits are so terribly bad that it would be cheaper time-wise to go back and click the link, rather than undoing the vandalism.

Comment: But when you click [Edit], you technically haven't done anything *yet*. You get audited as if you have done something. I don't think that's desired behavior in this case.

Comment: @Kuba In this case, it should be expected behavior - I could see where this could be useful, but we have to remember that when clicking edit you *start out with* the vandalized version of the post.