# "Looks Good" in "First Post" review

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Late Answers” and “First Posts” encouraging unnecessary actions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147867/late-answers-and-first-posts-encouraging-unnecessary-actions)

I was wondering why there's no Looks Good option in the *First Post* review queue.

Sometimes when I go through the queue of *First Post* I find some post which does not need any review: They have good formatting (maybe someone has edited it before), no suggestion needed for the user, or others change needed.

In this case, the only thing I can do to acknowledge the post is to upvote it, but sometimes I do not find the *question* worth an up-vote, or I am not sure (not knowing good enough the argument) if the *answer* deserve an up-vote.

In this case, a simple Looks Good option would be very handy!

Looking on this site, I found that the lots of post up-voted without reason (just to get review count) can damage the site; in my opinion a Looks Good button could be another solution to this problem. It is true that this won't solve the problem of people just pressing Looks Good randomly, but combining it with the removal of the up-vote button on *First Post*, could maybe help reducing the unnecessary up-voted question.

Do this make any sense, or am I doing wrong assumption on the meaning for Upvote/Looks Good and First Post review?

**EDIT:** *Reported from comment to kiamlaluno to better explain my thoughts:*

I understand your point of view however, even if I completely agree that if i am not expert and i cannot judge an answer i should Skip it, i still think that on questions you could say one is legit even if you are not a great expert. Skip button, i suppose, do not provide any opinion on the question, while a Looks Good would. Anyway is also true that there are so many reviewers that, even if noone think a question to be downvoted, eventually someone would find it useful and upvote it.

Comment: Your assumption that you should upvote such questions is incorrect.  If you don't see any action that should be taken the appropriate thing to do is press `Skip`.

Comment: It's exactly the opposite: i assume you should not vote such questions, but you should have a way to say that the question is ok even if it does not deserve upvote

Answer (score 2):

"Skip" is the equivalent of "Looks Good". I know it doesn't add to review count, but it's the proper choice in this case.

Comment: I don't think so. "Skip" means that you didn't review. "Looks Good" means that you reviewed it. It's not about your own review count, it is about the review queues review count. As long as everybody skips, the review keeps being open until it gets enough reviewers.

Comment: My answer was made before the Looks Good button was implemented. This question was in fact a feature request for that button.

Comment: True. But I think "Skip" was never the equivalent of "Looks Good".

Answer (score 2):

As it is now that queue, when you find a post for which you don't have anything to do with it, you need to click on the "Skip" button.
As you noted, voting a post just to be able to click on "I am done" is wrong, especially for bad questions that should be closed, or answers that are wrong. Keep also in mind that in the review queue you could be shown some audit posts: posts that have clearly bad, such as already deleted posts, which are shown you to see if you blindly take an action on posts shown in the review queues.

Removing the up-vote button is not what I would see implemented: There could be posts that are worth an up-vote, and I would like to be able to up-vote them. Eventually, it could be a solution to avoid a user up-votes X posts in row. I think the audit system used now should resolve the issue; in the case it doesn't resolve the issue, a limit about consecutive up-votes could be another way to avoid users blindly up-votes just to increase the number of their reviews.

Comment: I understand your point of view however, even if I completely agree that if i am not expert and i cannot judge an answer i should Skip it, i still think that on questions you could say one is legit even if you are not a great expert. Skip button, i suppose, do not provide any opinion on the question, while a Looks Good would. Anyway is also true that there are so many reviewers that, even if noone think a question to be downvoted, eventually someone would find it useful and upvote it

Comment: I don't find the link to the question right now, but when we were asked about the new review queues, I suggested the "I am done" button should be enabled from the first moment I see a post in a queue, or at least if I have already taken an action outside the review queues for that post (e.g. voting to close a question). I was said they don't want users to blindly click on "I am done" just to increase the number of reviews. I also suggested not to enable that button for who clicked it too much times in row.