# Are posts removed from the review queue if they get a 'No Action Needed' review?

Tags: support, review

As the review queue is empty these days, more so after the No Action Needed button was introduced, so, are posts removed from the review queue if they get a 'No  Action Needed' review ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presently yes.

Because, [@9 Shogs-a-Shogging♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/9-shogs-a-shogging) introduced this feature ('No Action Needed` button) via [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158761/187824). Where [I asked them to add those posts again in queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147867/late-answers-and-first-posts-encouraging-unnecessary-actions/158761#comment-459476). And [he replied they may add this feature in future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147867/late-answers-and-first-posts-encouraging-unnecessary-actions/158761#comment-459477).