# Reviewing finished after upvoting a comment

Tags: feature-request, review

I was reviewing a few Firsts Posts on Stackoverflow today. I am fully awaye that for the "I'm Done" button to enable, you must edit, flag or vote and so on, on the question. However I noticed that upvoting a comment enables it too. I personally don't think this should be considered as reviewing as it has nothing to do with the question. What does everyone else think?

Comment: Just FYI: When the First Posts queue was launched, upvoting comments did not enable the button. That was changed after [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146998/167534).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think upvoting comments is a valid way to complete a review, because someone might have written something that I would have written, too - to give a hint on how the OP could improve the question - without immediately up- or downvoting the question, because it's not bad enough to deserve a downvote, and not good enough (yet) to deserve an upvote either...

Comment: I see where you're coming from, however I just don't feel it properly reviews the question itself.

Comment: I disagree.  You're reviewing the comment and not the post itself.  I believe you should take action against the post or use a not-yet-provided neutral indication that the post is acceptable

Comment: Im this case upvoting the comment *is* in fact a neutral action: You don't vote on the question (that's the neutral part) but rather emphasize a comment that has been made aleady and you don't want to repeat. Other neutral actions are not required in my opinion because they would provide no feedback whatsoever to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You may be right about an upvote not being a worthy edit, but there does need to be a way for a reviewer to say that the post looks good.  The upvote is the only way that I know of to do that.  You imply that a more neutral action would be nice and I agree.

Comment: The OPs intention was about upvoting *comments* not the question itself...

Comment: My statement about the need for a neutral action and not an up vote still applies.