# Review Beta First Posts: I'm Done disabled if browser Back button used

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, new-users, back-button

In the new [First Posts review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146988/189912), if you take an action on the question, I'm Done becomes available to click on. However, after taking the action, if you click the browser's Back button and then Forward again, I'm Done is disabled again.

Closely related: Today I edited a question to improve it, coming from the review tool, and was surprised that after my edit I was taken back to the review page. I instinctively clicked Back before realizing I was already "back" there, and then went "forward" to get back to the review I'd been looking at, this is how I discovered the issue.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Take an action on a review. The action can be *any* of the possible actions.
2. Click Back on the browser.
3. Click Forward on the browser.

Expected behavior:

1. I'm Done is available and can be clicked.

Actual behavior:

1. I'm Done is disabled.

Additional information:

- Tested on Google Chrome 21 on Fedora 17.

Comment: Confirmed on Firefox 15 and Chrome 21.

Comment: [Same problem if you hit reload on the review page.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts/146999#146999)

Comment: More generally: [Activate “I'm Done” button in New Post Review queue if I have already acted on the post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147086/activate-im-done-button-in-new-post-review-queue-if-i-have-already-acted-on-t)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed now.

If, after taking a review action in the First Posts queue, you refresh the page or re-navigate to it via some other means, "I'm Done" should be enabled, and your review action will be recorded upon clicking it.