# Review tasks not anonymous

Tags: discussion, review

While trying to reproduce [the bug posted here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147036/review-beta-first-posts-im-done-disabled-if-browser-back-button-used), I noticed something peculiar.

When you completed a review of a post, your name shows up on top for other people to see.

[image]

I'm not sure how I feel about this. When I edit an item I reviewed, my name is added to the question or answer for obvious reasons. However, I expect *reading*, reviewing and voting to be completely anonymous.

I don't really see the added value of having this information, and to me it raises some minor privacy concerns.

Comment: If you weren't aware of it, most all of the review queues (before and after the overhaul) have done this, or something similar.

Comment: What kind of privacy concerns do you mean?

Comment: Well, when I post content, I expect my name to show up along side it, but when I'm just reviewing/reading other people's posts, I have the expectation of anonymity. Suppose for example that someone posts a first question and gets a downvote. When people see that question in the review page with "Kenny Rasschaert reviewed this", they might assume I made that downvote (and they could be right).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is consistent with all of the /review queue actions, with the exception of delete votes (and recommendations) which are excluded because deleted posts aren't visible.

The rationale is that you're actively doing something to be helpful and should be proud of it - note that these are also displayed in your profile's activity log.

Note that the First Posts queue is currently a bit special in that your activities there aren't specified - it will always just say "Reviewed" rather than "Voted" or "Edited". Internally, we do track the details of what *exactly* you're doing, but felt that exposing this would violate your privacy (particularly in the cases of voting and flagging).

Comment: Well, if I flag a post, the score remains zero, my name doesn't show up as "edited" on the post, and there aren't any comments from me - so by process of elimination, you can figure out what I did.  In fact, this goes for figuring out the action on most -1, 0, or 1 score posts - especially on slower sites.  Most worrysome is revealing who downvoted/flagged a post.