# Activate "I'm Done" button in New Post Review queue if I have already acted on the post

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

The Review Queue is not always the first place I visit when I hit a Stack Exchange site. I usually dive into the questions to see if there's something interesting that I can answer or something else obvious to be acted upon.

When I do get into Review and start looking through the First Posts queue, I'm presented with a question on which I've already voted, commented on, *and* edited. The <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button is, unfortunately not lit.

I don't want to make further (read: unnecessary) edits, so my only choice is to click <kbd>Not Sure</kbd>.

It would be better if the <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> was live if I've already taken some action on the post.

Alternatively, just don't show a New Post in the queue if I've already taken some action on it.

(This was alluded to in the comments on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146991/21960), but I thought I'd make it a formal feature request.)

Comment: Yes please. The old review system was smart enough to realize that I had already acted on the post and increase my counter accordingly. That seems a pretty good feature to keep.

Comment: Right now I'm going through week-old posts that I've already acted on, and it's getting on my nerves that I can't click `I'm done`.

Comment: The first part of this request is done. If you've already taken action on the post, "I'm Done" should be enabled already. We're working on implementing the second part: if you've already taken action on the post, you won't see it in the queue unless you specifically link to it.

Comment: Nice, but ATM it doesn't take flagged posts into account. Is this by design?

Comment: @Flow It's supposed to take flags into consideration. Do you know what type of flag it is, or which post?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I just read that only the first part was implemented. I guess the answer had the "I'm Done" button activated right from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, if you have already taken some sort of action on a post, you shouldn't randomly come across it in the First Posts queue. However, if you directly navigate to it (via reloading the page, back/forward, or permalink), it should still be reviewable, with the <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button enabled and clickable by default.